# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split

Почему не работает?

```
l = []
word = ['dog', 'cat']

l1 = print('/'.join(word))


def ap(l1):
    c = l1.split('/')
    for i in c:
        l.append(i)


ap(l1)

for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Ошибка:

```
dog/cat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timer.py", line 14, in <module>
    ap(l1)
  File "timer.py", line 9, in ap
    c = l1.split('/')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже понял)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как сказано в спеке:

> Функция Python print не возвращает значений; возвращает None.

Поэтому `l1` после строки `l1 = print('/'.join(word))` принимает значение `None`

Попробуйте так:

```
l = []
word = ['dog', 'cat']

l1 = '/'.join(word)
print(l1)


def ap(l1):
    c = l1.split('/')
    for i in c:
        l.append(i)


ap(l1)

for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе не надо выводить команду join. Так как ты выводишь команда print выведет None и не запишется в переменную

```
l = []
word = ['dog', 'cat']

l1 = '/'.join(word)

def ap(l1):
    global l

    l += l1.split('/')


ap(l1)

for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `join` таки как раз вернет новую строку, а вот `print` возвращает `None`

Comment: `global l` не нужен, т.к. не было присваивания переменной `l`, типо `l = [1, 2, 3]`. Кст, в `ap` весь код можно заменить на `l += l1.split('/')`